# Separate out (and keep) duplicate categorical data using Seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot some hypothetical student testing scores. I'd like to have student lastname on the y-axis and test score on the x-axis (horizontal barplot). Because Student names are non-unique, I'd like to *allow* duplicates on the y-axis. I've seen ways to get rid of duplicate data in seaborn and/or pandas, but not how to keep. Here's the code I have:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="whitegrid")

scores = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv', sep=',').sort_values("score", ascending=True)
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="score", y="lastName", data=scores, color="b", ci=None)
plt.title('Scores')
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
plt.savefig('path_to_file.pdf')
```

I thought that maybe I should be using factorplot and setting the orientation to "h" and type to "bar" but that produced a "tight layout" warning and, indeed, a tight/badly-rendered plot.

FYI, currently I have a barplot that looks nice enough, but it groups non-unique lastnames and sums their test scores; that's what I'm looking to fix.

Comment: Are you trying to display two bars for duplicate last names?

Comment: It would help if you posted sample data. Read how to create a [mcve]. I could try to make up sample data matching your code and description but that would take me time that would be better spend actually solving the issue and I could misunderstand you and write a useless answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can plot a bar for each unique row (by using the index as your y-coordinate), and then manually assign y-axis tick labels.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'score': [10, 20, 30, 40],
})

ax = sns.barplot(x=df.score, y=df.index, orient='h')
ax.set_yticklabels(df.name)
```

[image: sns.barplot]

---

Note that for this task, Seaborn might actually be overkill; you aren't doing any statistical visualization. Since you don't need to group non-unique values and display confidence intervals, `matplotlib.pyplot.barh` is sufficient (just `import seaborn` for good-looking plots).

```
plt.barh(df.index, df.score, align='center')
plt.yticks(df.index, df.name)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

[image: matplotlib.pyplot.barh]

Comment: Was about to post a slightly worse version of this. Well done.

Comment: Hey, @Igor, this seems like a potentially nice solution. Will it pose any problems for reading in a large csv file and sorting scores into ascending order, though?

Comment: @Janine, reading in/sorting the data and plotting it are two orthogonal tasks. You can use either of these methods to plot the data in any order you like.